# How one video overlay with 2 different videos with ffmpeg?

Tags: php, video, terminal, ffmpeg

How one video overlay with 2 different videos with ffmpeg?

I have code like this:

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mov -i ov1.mp4 -i ov2.mp4 \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+1/TB[v1];[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[v2];[v0][v1]overlay=enable='between(t,1,10)';[v0][v2]overlay=enable='between(t,10,15)'" \
    -t 30 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy \
    out.mp4
```

But for result i have, that one overlay video is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mov -i ov1.mp4 -i ov2.mp4 \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+1/TB[v1];[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[v2];[v0][v1]overlay=enable='between(t,1,10)'[v01];[v01][v2]overlay=enable='between(t,10,15)'" \
    -t 30 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy \
    out.mp4
```

The output of the first overlay has to be used as the input for the next.